# Can i deal with DevExpress GridView as smae as MS Gridview in windows form?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress, devextreme, invoice

Anyone knows if it's possible to deal with DevExpress GridView as same as we deal with Gridview which in MS Visual Studio Windows Form App?
Such as:

1. Creating a grid with 100 empty rows in default.
2. User can fill 1,7,20 or other number of rows then save them to DB.
3. Can type data directly in cells without any other form or popup...
4. Can make some validations and calculations while entering data in a row.
   And so on..

Finally, I need to create a web-based ASP.Net MVC invoice page using DevExpress tools.
I already made it using Windows Forms with pure MS components and now need to create same on ASP.Net MVC.
**In other words, i need a gridview Excel-like editing!**
* Attached image is my Windows Form Application.
Regards. [windows form App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmC74.png)

Answer (score 0):

Devexpress on MVC should have the capabilities you mention. I found these articles which look like they can help you with this task.

I would look at this demo on "Batch Editing" and see if it suits your needs: https://demos.devexpress.com/MVCxGridViewDemos/Editing/BatchEditing

This link talks about adding new rows on the client-side: https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t438193/gridview-how-to-add-new-row-to-empty-grid

This link also talks about binding on an empty grid and using the batch editing to add data on the client-side before saving it to the server:
https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/Ticket/Details/T694907/gridview-bind-an-empty-grid-with-option-to-add-and-delete-rows-on-the-client-side